# Can't upgrade or install programs because of Virtualbox extension

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, virtualbox, software-center

I have searched everywhere and tried everything I've found to no avail. Software updating, whether by apt-get update/upgrade or via the Software Updater, hangs when it tries to update a Virtualbox extension. I believe this started when I inadvertently updated while Virtualbox was open and ended up with an extension version mismatch with the Virtualbox version. I have since upgraded Virtualbox, matching the version with its extension. The problem is, Software update hasn't gotten that message and nothing I do seems to convince it otherwise.

I read that Synaptic might help me solve the problem but every time I try to install Synaptic (or any program for that matter), apt-get update fails, telling me I need to use sudo dpkg --configure -a which always ends up trying to upgrade the Virtualbox extension and tosses up a license agreement with no prompt to accept and locks the database so I have to reboot to even try again.

How oh how, great gods of Ubuntu, do I convince Software Update that the Virtualbox extension does NOT need to be updated? Is there a script I can edit? A database I can reconfigure? I don't believe uninstalling and purging Virtualbox would do anything as the problem seems to be in the Software Updater. Please, before I tear what's left of my hair out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cant tell from what you have told us. Open a terminal and enter the following commands `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install && apt-get upgrade` post any and all errors.

Comment: Can't get past apt-get update.

Comment: You need to copy-paste the full output of the commands, use ubuntu pastebin for long output - https://paste.ubuntu.com/ or use pastebinit if it is installed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to paste that information here. apt-get update fails stating that I have to run sudo dpkg --configure -a which fails when it tries to install the Virtualbox extension (which Vbox doesn't need). The problem is with the software updater trying to update something that doesn't need updating. I think.

Comment: You copy paste from the terminal same as any other program. Select the text copy from terminal menu paste into your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I may be a Ubuntu novice but I'm a persistent Ubuntu novice and I knew if I kept picking at this long enough I'd figure it out.

I found a very old article (2008) describing a similar situation and figured, why not, give it a shot. And it worked.

sudo dpkg --audit gave me this:
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 alacarte             easy GNOME menu editing tool
 python-gi            Python 2.x bindings for gobject-introspection libraries

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure  or the configure menu option in dselect:
 virtualbox-ext-pack  extra capabilities for VirtualBox, downloader.

I then ran: sudo dpkg -r virtualbox-ext-pack which led to this:
(Reading database ... 745263 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-ext-pack (5.0.36-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Successfully uninstalled "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack".
Successfully performed extension pack cleanup

And finally sudo apt-get update which finally finished completely.